# Mild pain in lower forearms during biking

Tags: frames, bike-fit, health, urban-riding

I feel some pressure and fatigue in my wrists and lower forearms during riding but not after it. I don't know whether it is due to weakness of my wrists or my suspicion that my 18" frame mount bike is small for my 6'1" height. But the thing is that I don't feel any fatigue after biking; only during it. What do you think the problem is?

Comment: There are many potential reasons. Here are some thoughts that might help us help you. Are you gripping very tight? Covering the brakes all the time? If the latter, does the angle feel natural? What tyres/pressure/road surface? Gloves?

Comment: @ChrisH Thank you but not really. My grip is usually very loose and I don't touch the brakes most of the time; only when it is needed. I mostly ride in the city on plain streets. Tyre pressures are also fine.

Comment: @ChrisH, I wanted to say "but not really" was related to your questions. I thought it might be misread. Sorry.

Comment: If the bike is fitting properly, which you have your own reservations about, the pain of riding is inversely proportional to practice, especially where hands, wrists or arms are concerned. In other words, it will go away some day.

Answer (score 5):

Fatigue indicates you are using the muscle, so you will need to “check into” yourself to see how/why you are firing your forearm muscle, what task is it trying to accomplish.

Sometimes we just have some odd or peculiar habits we are unaware we are doing. For example, my wife used to complain about wrist and hand pain when riding her flat bar commute bike until I observed she held her wrists in heavy dorsiflexion when she gripped the bar. Retraining how she held flat bar grips (i.e., a wrist angle of zero) alleviated the symptoms.

[image: illustration of dorsiflexion]

Finally, as other answers indicted some component of bike fit could also be the culprit, but there is not enough information to comment on this possibility.

Comment: Changing hand position frequently, frequently helps. A drop bar offers more possible hand positions than a straight bar but still. And taking one hand off the bar, shaking, repeating with the other is another good way to release tension.

Answer (score 3):

> What do you think the problem is?

I think your bike does not fit properly. But it's impossible for anyone here to give you advice with a remote diagnosis. you should really go to your local bike shop and spend the money for a bike fit. this will really help you and clarify what the problem is.

you should take notes at the bike fit and mark your seat post height etc.
so you could fit any new bike in your life for your requirements and won't have the same problems ever again because of an unfitting bike.